# Sorting a datatable with datatable.DefaultView.Sort

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to sort a datatable. But it's not working.

```
arr[0] = "name"; 
arr[1] = "DESC";

myDataSet.Tables["table1"].DefaultView.Sort = arr[0] + " " + arr[1];
```

Here, `myDataSet` refers to dataset I'm using for the reportviewer.

Am I missing something? Is there any other way?

Comment: are you sending the default view back to your report Viewer?. past the bind method as well.

Comment: The code is correct, but what matter here is how the dataview is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remmber that you have to use the default view as your new data source for the viewer.

Call your bind method with the defaultView property and then [ToTable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8ycds2f.aspx)